# PostgreSQL Group By query result does not show group values, only column name

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I am performing a GROUP BY query on a PostgreSQL database but the results are not showing correctly.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    'ship_class',
    AVG(dead_weight),
    AVG(length),
    AVG(beam) 
FROM 
    ais 
WHERE 
    dead_weight != -1 AND dead_weight IS NOT NULL 
    AND length != -1 AND length IS NOT NULL 
    AND beam != -1 AND beam IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY
    ship_class;
```

And here is the result:

```
  ?column?  |        avg         |         avg          |         avg         
------------+--------------------+----------------------+---------------------
 ship_class |  392.9976146302677 |  48.1044261860588391 | 12.8234826398091704
 ship_class |   71.5188492063492 |  40.4335317460317460 | 11.1041666666666667
 ship_class |  67566.23277656965 | 233.8205246842178319 | 35.2444824873918475
 ship_class | 13522.685408299865 | 150.7456492637215529 | 22.4805890227576975
```

Here is an example of what the data looks like in the table I am querying

```
  ship_class|      dead_weight   |         length       |         beam         
------------+--------------------+----------------------+---------------------
 Class A    |      340           |           38         |          9
 Class B    |       68           |           41         |          9
 Class D    |      5500          |          205         |         37
 Class C    |      2000          |          135         |         21
 Class B    |      340           |           38         |          9
 Class B    |       68           |           41         |          9
 Class C    |      5500          |          205         |         37
 Class D    |      2000          |          135         |         21
```

The column ship class has values Class A, Class B, Class C, and Class D, so why is the result not showing these and just showing the column name? I cannot tell which result corresponds to which class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are quoting first column, `'ship_class'`.  Try just using `ship_class`.

Comment: Yep that fixed it, wow, thanks for the answer. I could have sworn I already tried that. Guess it's just one of those days haha. Thanks!